# Bootstrap Mobile Responsiveness issues

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make my portfolio responsive but having some issues with bootstrap.

I have 4 divs which should take up the width of the screen evenly.  I have a class of `row d-none d-sm-block` on it.  This should hide this set of divs and toggle my mobile view when the screen falls below 576 pixels.  This seems to be working.

I also have a `col-sm-3` on each of the 4 divs.  This is looks like the problem.  It supposed to take up the width evenly and it does - Until you get to a width of 770 pixels or below then the divs stack in 4 rows instead of one.  When the width of the screen gets to about 760 pixels

[image]

Upon inspection it looks like the column is taking up the whole width of the screen for some reason.  I can't figure out what the issue is.  The entire website can be found on heroku.  You'd have to scroll down to "Main Technology Stack":

https://mighty-ocean-12133.herokuapp.com/

Here's a code snippet of what I have:

```
        <div className="container">
      <div className="row d-none d-sm-block">
        <div style={{cursor: "pointer"}} className="col-sm-3" onMouseOver={this.openBox.bind(this,'ReactJS')} onMouseLeave={this.fadeIn.bind(this, 'ReactJS')}>
          <img width="100%" height="100%" src="/assets/ReactJS.png" alt=""></img>                  
        </div>
        <div style={{cursor: "pointer"}} className="col-sm-3" onMouseOver={this.openBox.bind(this,'AngularJS')} onMouseLeave={this.fadeIn.bind(this, 'AngularJS')}>
          <img width="100%" height="100%" src="/assets/AngularJS.png" alt=""></img>                  
        </div>
        <div style={{cursor: "pointer"}} className="col-sm-3" onMouseOver={this.openBox.bind(this,'Java')} onMouseLeave={this.fadeIn.bind(this, 'Java')}>
          <img width="100%" height="100%" src="/assets/Java.jpg" alt=""></img>                  
        </div>
        <div style={{cursor: "pointer"}} className="col-sm-3" onMouseOver={this.openBox.bind(this,'Accessibility')} onMouseLeave={this.fadeIn.bind(this, 'Accessibility')}>
          <img width="100%" height="100%" src="/assets/Accessibility.png" alt=""></img>                  
        </div>
      </div>   
      <div className="row d-block d-sm-none">

        <div style={{cursor: "pointer"}} className="col-md-3">
          <img src="/assets/ReactJS.png" alt=""></img>                  
        </div>
        <div style={{cursor: "pointer"}} className="col-md-3">
          <img src="/assets/AngularJS.png" alt=""></img>                  
        </div>
        <div style={{cursor: "pointer"}} className="col-md-3">
          <img src="/assets/Java.jpg" alt=""></img>                  
        </div>
        <div style={{cursor: "pointer"}} className="col-md-3">
          <img src="/assets/Accessibility.png" alt=""></img>                  
        </div>
      </div>           
    </div>
```

Any other random comments on my portfolio is appreciated as well.

Comment: As you have illustrated the Portfolio url, Are you expecting only the four icons in a single row or want the entire page help?

Comment: I want the 4 icons in a single row

Comment: Is answer helped you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `d-flex flex-row` with combination of `justify-content-around` or `justify-content-between`

I have used `Bootstrap 4` here.

[image]

```html
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid bg-light">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row d-flex flex-row justify-content-around">
                <div class="border border-dark">
                    <img src="./images/reactjs.png" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="border border-dark">
                    <img src="./images/angularjs.png" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="border border-dark">
                    <img src="./images/java.png" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="border border-dark">
                    <img src="./images/accessibility.png" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Looks like it worked!  Just trying to understand though, should I be using "flex" instead of "display" for any mobile responsiveness or was mine just a special case?

Comment: @MatTaNg If using `Bootstrap`, let the `Bootstrap` decide and handle the breakpoint responsiveness. Also I shown each and every breakpoints for responsiveness.

Comment: Yeah, what I used was also part of the bootstrap library but perhaps I should just use the 'd-flex' instead of the 'd-sm-block' property for now on.  Thanks ofr you help.